# Why does the count() function require a parameter?

Tags: sql-server

The `count()` function counts rows, and is very often used as `count(*)`.  If I had a table with phoneNo and firstName, `count(phoneNumber)` returns the same number as `count(*)`.  All columns are always present, if not populated, in each row.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.

If you specify a field , count(fieldname) will count records which have *non null* values for the field. count(*) will give you total rows.

Answer (score 11):

On the other hand you can count distinct values. count(distinct firstName) may deliver a different result as count(distinct phoneNumber) and both may be different to count().

Comment: I had no idea you could use the distinct keyword in that position. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Count(phoneNo) will return the number of records where phoneNo is not null. Count(*) returns the number or rows regardless.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` will count every row. `COUNT(yourColumn)` won't include rows where `yourColumn` is `NULL`.

For example, if there are 20 rows in your table and the `phoneNumber` column is `NULL` in 5 of those rows, then `COUNT(*)` will return 20 whereas `COUNT(phoneNumber)` will return 15.